# Does this function returns a proper R-value reference or does it returns a copy?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

```
Quaternion&& GetInverse() const
{
     return Quaternion( GetConjugate() / GetSquaredMagnitude() ); 
}
```

I wanna know what will be returned, and if it is more efficient to indeed return an Rvalue, or to simply return a copy.

Or maybe I am completely wrong and there simply is no copy here.
Any information will be greatly appreciated. ^^;

Comment: looks like premature optimization. If you want to return an object then return an object. It really is as simple as that

Comment: Depending on how you call this function, you should probably just return a copy and rely on [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: :/c Hm.. I see, but what does it do memory-wise to just "return an object" as you say (which I would then assume to be without any "&")?

Comment: @TOFFY0312 Without copy-elision, it would call the Quaternion constructor to create the object and the copy constructor when returning from the function, then the destructor for the first object. But since copy-elision exists (see the link in my previous comment), it only calls the constructor once. (As if you would use a reference, but on the stack, which is harder to get wrong).

Comment: @eike I'll go check it out then, thank you ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Quaternion&&` is an r-value reference, but it is still a reference. In your code example you're returning a reference to a temporary object that will be destoroyed after `GetInverse()` returns and the reference will dangle. It is not an optimization, it is undefined behaviour.

Modern compilers are able to detect such errors. For example, GCC [complains](https://godbolt.org/z/vTGv1a):

```
warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    8 |      return Quaternion();
```

Returning by value is the best option here. Since C++17 copy elision is [mandatory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in such cases.